# CSS scrollabr doesn't appear (overflow-y)

Tags: css, height, scrollbar

I am trying to get a scrollbar working for about 30 minutes now. I read forums and stuff, and I guess it has something to do with my website height. I want the scrollbar only be visible on the  `<main>`  tag. I first thought I just haven't enough content, but after adding lorem ipsum text I really don't know, what the reason could be.

The Code:

```
body,
html {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#Wrapper {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;


}

header {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 1 80;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-radius: 0em 0em 1em 1em;
}

#branding {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    color: lawngreen;
}


.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.navitem {
    list-style: none;
}

.navitem a {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.navitem a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}


main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid Maroon;
    border-top: 0px;
}

main h2 {
    margin: 1em;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

main h4 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

table {
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

table tr {}

table td {
    padding: 2em;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Einfache-Rezepte</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Baloo+Bhaijaan|Gloria+Hallelujah|PT+Sans+Narrow|Righteous|Titillium+Web|Yanone+Kaffeesatz" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Diese Seite wird im Laufe der Zeit (hoffentlich) Rezepte beinhalten">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">

        <header>
            <h1 id="branding">Einfache-Rezepte</h1>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Einfache Rezeptideen für jeden leicht zu machen!</h2><br>

            <h4>Top Rezepte der Woche</h4>

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nummer</th>
                        <th>Gericht</th>
                        <th>Zeit</th>
                        <th>Bild</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nummer</td>
                        <td>Gericht</td>
                        <td>Zeit</td>
                        <td>Bild</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>


            </table>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBKENL

PS: On the CodePen it seems to work?!

PPS: It'S working on the CodePen, but I can't scroll to the bottomest. There is more Lorem Text within the HTML.

Comment: you have overflow hidden on the body and html, that's why you can't see the whole text.

Comment: If I remove the overflow-y: hidden from the body/html, I can scroll down, but I don't want the scrollbar shown on the right site from the page. I just want it on the main-tag, where I can see the "bar" from the scrollbar, but I can't scroll within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapper should be 100vh not "main". main should be 100vh - the height of the header. I've also removed the min-height: 100% from main. And you should use overflow-y: auto instead of scroll in case you don't have enough content.

```css
body,
html {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

#Wrapper {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    height: 100vh;

}

header {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 1 80;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-radius: 0em 0em 1em 1em;
    height: 56px;
}

#branding {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    color: lawngreen;
}


.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.navitem {
    list-style: none;
}

.navitem a {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.navitem a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}


main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid Maroon;
    border-top: 0px;
}

main h2 {
    margin: 1em;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

main h4 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

table {
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

table tr {}

table td {
    padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
 <div id="Wrapper">

        <header>
            <h1 id="branding">Einfache-Rezepte</h1>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Rezepte</a></li>
                <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Einfache Rezeptideen für jeden leicht zu machen!</h2><br>

            <h4>Top Rezepte der Woche</h4>

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nummer</th>
                        <th>Gericht</th>
                        <th>Zeit</th>
                        <th>Bild</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nummer</td>
                        <td>Gericht</td>
                        <td>Zeit</td>
                        <td>Bild</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>


            </table>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p>
<p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p><p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p>
<p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p>
<p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: For some reason, there is no difference in the result.

Comment: My bad. Updated the fiddle.

Comment: Worked! So it can just work, if the header has a specific height, for example 56 px? Or is there an automatic "vh"-calculation, if the header expands, for example by adding text under the current text, which would make the header "higher"..

Comment: it was easyer this way. You can make the main take up the remaining space, depending on the header's height. The ideea for what you're trying to achive is that header height + main height should be = 100vh

Comment: perfect, I understood it :D I tested it with adding a 20px footer UNDER the main-tag, and changed the "100vh - 56px" to "100vh - 76px" and it worked like it should. It's not that complicated, if you understand it once.

Comment: glad I could help